# How can I find the ways that a word can be read when it seems to be read back and forth?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:
The diagram shows a sequence of letters displaying the word "NOSUBASABUSON". How many ways can this word be read?.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&3200\\
2.&2480\\
3.&3000\\
4.&1600\\
\end{array}$

How exactly can I find those ways?. What I've attempted to do is to count individually from the left to the right and adding in tandem all of them.

This can be seen in the sketch from below:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

But the part where I'm confused is what would it be the total. Adding the last column results in $400+400+800=1600$ ways.

But this can be read in two ways from left to right and from right to left. Which accounts for two ways but upon looking in the S where it is labeled by $40$ I could spot that you can read the word form that place and returning back to the right. But I don't know how to account for that way.

Thus I am not sure if it would be $3200$ or $4800$?. Can someone help me here?. Can an answer **please include some drawing** so I could see if my approach was right?.

Comment: Hint: The diagram is symmetric about the middle S.

Comment: @JVV I also noticed that, and **if** you read my question I am stuck exactly on **how** to account for that fact.

Comment: If you count the fact that you could go back, then there are $6400$ since there would be $4$ ways to make the Word: (1) left to right, (2) left to left, (3) right to left, (4) right to right.

Comment: Is there a reason not to read top left N, bottom first O? and so on?

Comment: @AlainRemillard Howdy! I'm reviewing this problem but **I'm still confused**. The answer you obtained is two times the biggest answer given in the alternatives. Why is this?. Can you help me with this part?.Could it be that are you counting twice or something?.